# SASS ignores @import-ed file in CSS generation

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I can't get is it bug or feature of SASS.

Let's say, I have such **test.scss** file:

```
.test {
  margin: 0;
}
```

It is compiled into *test.css*. Good.

I have another **test2.scss** with such a code:

```
.test2 {
padding: 0;
}
```

Which is compiled into *test2.css*. Also good.

But, if I add **@import "test";** in **test2.scss**, then *test.css* stops compiling.

[Official documentation says](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials):

> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don’t want to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning of the filename.

From this I can understand, that *test.css* **must** compile in any case. It's compilation can be disabled **only** by adding underscore in the beginnig of SCSS filename.

Or I misenderstand something? Please, explain me.

My environemnt: Windows 7, css files are compiled by File Watchers in PhpStorm, SASS version - Media Mark (3.2.12)

**UPDATE (20.11.13)**
It appeared, that it is an issue with PhpStrom's File Watcher/ More info can be found at [this topic](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451040).

Comment: Try defining test.scss as a partial by renaming It to _test.scss. See: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: @Jop tried this too, but nothing changes. Seems, that imported file is always interpreted as partial, regardless of it's name.

Comment: I am using sass 3.2.12 and it compiles the `@import` file so should be a problem of File Watchers. But why would you want to compile a file that is already included in another? Can you explain what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @AlexGuerrero we have a product drop-down component with it's own stylesheet productDropdown.scss (compiled to CSS). This dropdown is included at product pages (programatically), therefore product.scss imports productDropdown.scss. But we're working in CMS and editor is able to add drop-down component anywhere on website, so we need to include css file of dropdown dynamically, therefore it needs to be existing separately. As for File Watchers, I'll try native watcher of SASS tomorrow and report result here. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexGuerrero I've made a test and it appears, that there is some issue with PhpStorm's File Watcher. Native SASS watcher compiles both files. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexGuerrero suggestion, and *Andriy Bazanov* answer problem is finally solved.

The reason was in PhpStorm's SCSS File Watcher setting **"Track only root files"**.

[Help of PhpStorm says](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/new-watcher-dialog.html):

> When the File Watcher is invoked on a file, PhpStorm detects all the
>   files in which this file is included. For each of these files, in its
>   turn, PhpStorm again detects the files into which it is included. This
>   operation is repeated recursively until PhpStorm reaches the files
>   that are not included anywhere within the specified scope. These files
>   are referred to as root files (do not confuse with content roots).
>
> - When this check box is selected the File Watcher runs only against    the root files.
> - When the check box is cleared, the File Watcher runs    against the file from which it is invoked and against all the files    in which
>     this file is included recursively within the specified    scope.

In my case this checkbox was selected, so I unselected it and now I've got expected behaviour.